# Inequality with sum of inverses of consecutive numbers

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Prove that
> $1 \leq  \frac{1}{1001} + \frac{1}{1002} +\dots+\frac{1}{3001} \leq \frac{4}{3} $

it seems from some Olympiad. i tried using sum of series etc. but could not get it.

Answer (score 2):

$ab \le \left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2$.

$(1000+n)(3002-n)\le 2001^2 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{1000+n} + \frac{1}{3002-n} \ge \frac{2}{2001}, n = 1, 2, \dots, 1000$.

$\frac{1}{1001} + \dots + \frac{1}{3001} = \sum^{1000}_{n=1}\left(\frac{1}{1000+n} + \frac{1}{3002-n}\right) + \frac{1}{2001} 
\ge 1000\times \frac{2}{2001} + \frac{1}{2001} =1$.

Comment: any idea about the upper bound

Answer (score 1):

For an upper bound, the sum is less than $\int_{1001}^{3001}dx/x=\ln x...$

Answer (score 0):

For one inequality you can use A.M-G.M Inequality...$$\frac{1001+1002+\dots+3001}{??}\geq \frac{??}{\frac{1}{1001}+\frac{1}{1002}+\dots+\frac{1}{3001}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since the function $1/x$ is convex and decreasing, it is easy to estimate the difference between it and the integral. I am not sure that an Olympiad problem that requires you to know $\log 3$ is a particularly good problem...

Comment: Tangent-line manipulations gives a good match in a small interval like $(e,3)$: $lne=1$, then $ln(e+.3)$~$lne+(2/3)(0.3)$~$1.2$ (use 2/3 as average of $1/x$ at $x=1$ and $x=1/3$) . It is reasonably-good unless you need to raise $ln3$ to some large power.