# Bounds on $S = \frac{1}{1001} + \frac{1}{1002}+ \frac{1}{1003}+\dots+\frac{1}{3001}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, summation, contest-math

> $S =  \frac{1}{1001} +   \frac{1}{1002}+ \frac{1}{1003}+ \dots+\frac{1}{3001}$.

> Prove that $\dfrac{29}{27}<S<\dfrac{7}{6}$.

My Attempt:
$S<\dfrac{500}{1000} +   \dfrac{500}{1500}+ \dfrac{500}{2000}+ \dfrac{500}{2500}+\dfrac{1}{3000} =\dfrac{3851}{3000}$

(Taking 250 terms together involves many fractions and is difficult to calculate by hand.)

Using AM-HM inequality gave me $S > 1$, but the bounds are weak.

[Prove that $1<\frac{1}{1001}+\frac{1}{1002}+\frac{1}{1003}+\dots+\frac{1}{3001}<\frac43$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688432) 
[Inequality with sum of inverses of consecutive numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605111) 
The answers to these questions are nice, but the bounds are weak.

Any help without calculus and without calculations involving calculators would be appreciated.

(I encountered this question when I was preparing for a contest which neither allows calculators nor calculus(Only high-school mathematics.))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Upper bound $\dfrac{7}{6}$

Your question describes a method of breaking the range up into sub-ranges, and then estimating the sum over a sub-range by noting that each term is $\le$ the first term. But we can do much better if we estimate this sum using a linear approximation instead. Then we only need three sub-ranges to establish the upper bound of $\frac76$.

Consider a 'graph' of the function $$f(k)=\frac{1}{k}$$ for integers $k\ge 1$. If we look at any interval $m\le k\le n$ with $1\le m\le n-2$, we can compare it with the straight-line function joining points $(m,\frac{1}{m})$ and $(n,\frac{1}{n})$. We can define this function explicitly if you want, as:
$$g(k)=\frac{1}{n-m}\left(\frac{k-m}{n}+\frac{n-k}{m}\right)$$
Then $f(m)=g(m),f(n)=g(n)$; and for $m<k<n,f(k)<g(k)$ (because $f$ is a convex function).

So $$\sum_{k=m}^nf(k)<\sum_{k=m}^ng(k)$$
But the $g(k)$ are in arithmetic progression, so the RHS is half the sum of the first and the last terms multiplied by the number of terms, i.e.
$$\frac{n-m+1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

We divide the range into three equal sub-ranges of size $667$. This gives us:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1001}^{3001}\frac{1}{k} & =\sum_{k=1001}^{1667}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=1668}^{2334}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=2335}^{3001}\frac{1}{k}\\
& <\frac{667}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1001}+\frac{1}{1667}\right)+\frac{667}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1668}+\frac{1}{2334}\right)+\frac{667}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2335}+\frac{1}{3001}\right)\\
& <\frac{667}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1000.5}+\frac{1}{1667.5}+\frac{1}{1667.5}+\frac{1}{2334.5}+\frac{1}{2334.5}+\frac{1}{3001.5}\right)\\
& =\frac13+\frac15+\frac15+\frac17+\frac17+\frac19\\
& =\frac{356}{315}\\
& <\frac{7}{6}\end{align}$$

where we have used the fact that $\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{m-\frac12}+\frac{1}{n+\frac12}$ if $m<n$, again by convexity of $f(k)$.

Note that if the last term were $\frac{1}{3000}$, we could do this with just two sub-ranges, and we would get exactly $\frac{7}{6}$ as a bound. So perhaps I have missed an easier way.

### Lower bound $\dfrac{29}{27}$

This time we use the convexity of the function to estimate the sum over a sub-range from below. The sum of $\frac{1}{k}$ over the range $m\le k\le n$ is greater than the number of elements multiplied by the middle element if the range contains an odd number of elements. So we get
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1001}^{3001}\frac{1}{k} & =\sum_{k=1001}^{1667}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=1668}^{2334}\frac{1}{k}+\sum_{k=2335}^{3001}\frac{1}{k}\\
& > 667\left(\frac{1}{1334}+\frac{1}{2001}+\frac{1}{2668}\right)\\
& = \frac12+\frac13+\frac14\\
& = \frac{13}{12}\\
& >\frac{29}{27}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Shouldn't the upper limit on the second sum be 3001.  You then won't quite get $7/6$ unless you tweak the ranges.

Comment: @WADon: Oh, you're right. I'll take my answer off-line while I figure it out.

Comment: @WADon: I think it's correct now.

Comment: Good work.  I thought something like this should work.  But one thing nags me:  $29$ is a factor of $2001$ and I thought surely the numerator of $29/27$ would come from that.

Comment: Your derivation for  lower  bound looks awesome!(+1)

Answer (score 2):

We can find an *approximation* of the result.

Consider
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2001}\frac1{1000+i}=\sum_{i=1}^{3001}\frac1{i}-\sum_{i=1}^{1000}\frac1{i}$$ and we shall use the fact that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{i}=H_n$$

Now, the asymptotics of harmonic numbers
$$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2
   n}-\frac{1}{12 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$ Using it twice and you will have sharper bounds.

Comment: I appreciate it but I have not learned about the asymptotics of Harmonic Numbers and also the contest I am preparing for allows only High school mathematics. If I am not wrong that is derived using calculus.

Comment: @Forester. Sorry for that ! Don't worry : you will learn that very soon. On that day, remember me ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I for sure will. :-)

Comment: However, the $O(1/n^4)$ does not give any hint on how large it can get, so it's not usable as is to get an approximation within known bounds. We only know it will eventually get small as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The point is that $H_{n}$ is between $\lambda + log(n) + 1/2n$ and $\lambda + log(n) +1/2n - 1/12n^{2}$. The  $O(1/n^{4})$ term is not needed.

Comment: @Salcio Which remains to be proved. It's not a consequence of the asymptotic formula. Besides, without further information, as far as we know, the $O(1/n^4)$ term could be much larger than the other ones for $n<3000$ (I know it isn't, but the asymptotic formula that is written here does not guarantee that).

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the sum into groups as you have done will obtain the limits if you take enough buckets (around 10).

A similar approach is to add $1/1000$ and then pair the terms, with two terms left over added to the end
\begin{align}
S&=\frac{1}{1000} + \frac{1}{3000} + \frac{1}{1001} + \frac{1}{2999} + \cdots + 
\frac{1}{1999} + \frac{1}{2001} + \frac{1}{3001} - \frac{1}{1000} \\
&= \frac{4000}{1000\cdot 3000} + \frac{4000}{1001\cdot 2999} + \cdots +\frac{4000}{1999\cdot 2001} + \frac{1}{3001}-\frac{1}{1000}
\end{align}

Then try grouping these into $m$ buckets, each with $n$ terms.  The lower bound is
\begin{align}
\frac{4000n}{(1000+n-1)(3000-n+1)}+\cdots+\frac{4000n}{(1000+mn-1)(3000-mn+1)} \\ \quad+\frac{1}{3001}-\frac{1}{1000}
\end{align}
and the upper bound,
\begin{align}
\frac{4000n}{(1000)(3000)}+\cdots+\frac{4000n}{(1000+(m-1)n)(3000-(m-1)n)}\\ \quad+\frac{1}{3001}-\frac{1}{1000}
\end{align}
Using a calculator, and (still) choosing $m=4, n=250$ can create bounds comparable to the ones you have, but it is still cumbersome.

---

With $n=250$, the upper bound is
\begin{align}
U &= \frac{1}{3}+\frac{16}{55}+\frac{4}{15}+\frac{16}{63}+\frac{1}{3001}-\frac{1}{1000} \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{3}+\frac{16}{55}+\frac{4}{15}+\frac{16}{63} \\
&\leqslant \frac{20 + 18+16+16}{60} \\
&= \frac{7}{6}
\end{align}

Comment: Nice approach, but I am actually looking for a solution that does not involve big calculations(calculations that do not require a calculator) and I am sure there is a solution like that.

Comment: @Forester: Why are you sure there is a solution like that?

Comment: Fair enough.  With just 4 terms you could probably soldier through the calculation by hand but I hope you find a neater solution.  In the meantime, I have edited and slightly simplified the approach I offered to make the sums a little easier.

Comment: @TonyK Because the contest I am preparing for does not allow calculators. I am preparing for RMO/INMO. Those are Indian olympiads leading to the IMO.

Comment: @TonyK https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/about-olympiads/stages/mathematical-olympiad/

Comment: @Forester: It would be helpful to include relevant data like that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well not an answer but an idea to inspire someone :

I remenber the Gauss's solution of the first case concerning the Faulhaber's formula :

We have :

$$\frac{1}{1001}+\frac{1}{3001}>\frac{1}{1002}+\frac{1}{3000}>\cdots>\frac{1}{2002}+\frac{1}{2000}$$

Wich gives :

$$S<\frac{1000}{1001}+\frac{1000}{3001}+\frac{1}{2001}$$

Now if we divide (3001-1001) by four we get :

$$\frac{500}{2500}+\frac{500}{2502}+\frac{1}{2501}+\frac{499}{1499}+\frac{499}{1501}+\frac{1}{1500}<S<\frac{500}{1001}+\frac{500}{2000}+\frac{1}{1500}+\frac{499}{2001}+\frac{499}{3001}+\frac{1}{2500}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2001}\frac{1}{1000\left(1+\frac{n}{1000}\right)} =\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1}{\left(1+x\right)}dx \approx \ln3$$

$$\frac{29}{27} < \ln3 <\frac{7}{6}$$

Used:

1. Summation to integration when step size is small

Comment: Nice solution but that involves calculus.

Comment: @Forester I think applying calculus would appropriately fit your primary condition which is to `calculate less` .

Comment: Well the main condition is that I encountered this question while preparing for a contest(RMO/INMO) in which neither calculator nor calculus is allowed

Comment: @Forester nice to hear you are preparing for RMO! i passed PRMO then flunked in RMO(dont ask me my score too embarrssed to tell)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Even I passed PRMO and then flunked in RMO last year.

Comment: @Forester we are in the same boat then,:)